# XSLT to extract URL Parameters

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

can anyone help me to find a way to extract some parameters from URL and save pass it into soap request

**URL**

https://hostname/ServiceName?Consumer=ABS&ID=3231

I'd take only Consumer name which is ABS and it's id = 3231 and put it into soap as below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<Consumer>ABS</Consumer>
<ID>3231<ID>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Do you have an input xml already that you can pass into xslt or do you just want to format your data like this? Should be possible in every language.

Comment: I do not think you will need xslt. Especially because you will not get many views / answers to it since its another topic. I would rather google something like 'js url parameters' and 'js soap request'. I am assuming you are using java script and there are plenty of answers regarded to this topic already on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 or higher, you can use the `xsl:analyze-string` instruction to extract **all** query parameters from a URL string:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$URL" regex="[\?&amp;]([^=]+)=([^&amp;]+)">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:element name="{regex-group(1)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

---

**Demo**: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfr

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use string formatting functions along with hard coded element name in result

```
<xsl:variable name="URL">https://hostname/ServiceName?Consumer=ABS&amp;ID=3231</xsl:variable>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Consumer>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($URL,'Consumer='),'&amp;')"/>
        </Consumer>
        <ID>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($URL,'ID=')"/>
        </ID>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```